# Django: Cannot resolve keyword ''hidden_from_cus" into field. Choices are

Tags: python, django

I've the following model:

```
class Task(models.Model)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    external_job = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

I added a column hidden_from_customer as:

```
hidden_from_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and ran the syncdb. The column is now reflecting in the database with default value as True. But when I run the following query:

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(status=1, hidden_from_customer=True)
```

I get the exception saying:

```
Cannot resolve keyword "hidden_from_customer" into field. Choices are customer, external_job, created, start, status.
```

I don't know what's wrong in this!

Comment: Which version of django are you using?

Comment: I am pretty sure that a FieldError, which this is, is an exception on the fields in the model, not with a database query itself. In other words, it is not that the table does not exist in the database because it never gets that far. Are you sure that you re-loaded the model after you added the field?

Comment: Thanks guys but it was the error in the definition of the model. Kindly see the solution I've posted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've the solution. In the database, I saw that there was an extra column 'end' which was not defined in the Model. That's why I think Django was not looking at the new column. I've added back 'end' in the model and now everything is working well.

Strangely, everything was working well until I added this new column.

Comment: I would be wary of this as a red herring unless you can duplicate the problem exactly by adding/removing said column and reloading the model(s). In all my Django experience, Django has never cared about a column existing in the database that is not defined in the model and that error message would not come about because of an extra column.